# What time does it take for irrational rotations to hit an interval?

Tags: ergodic-theory, pr.probability

Hi,

Consider $\theta_n = (\theta_0 + n \theta) \mod 1$, $\theta$ being an irrational number, and $\theta_0$ an uniform random variable in $(0,1)$. Is there any estimates for the time it will take this process to hit $(0,\alpha)$ ? From the ergodic theorem I know that, if I denote $N(n)$ the number of times $\theta_n \in (0,\alpha)$, then $N(n)/n \to \alpha$. What I want to know is how much time it will take for this limit to be attained.

Another way of framing this question is : is there any "central limit theorem" (or weakening thereof ; I'm mainly interested in guaranteed bounds for $P(N\geq 1)$) for ergodic processes? From what I've read, there is no general answer to this for a generic ergodic process and function f. There are some results that depend on $f$ being smooth, which it isn't here.

The same question was asked on [Quantitative versions of ergodic theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4411/quantitative-versions-of-ergodic-theorem), but I haven't found anything there that relates to my question.

Comment: This is a tricky one. In  Chapter 2, Section 3 of  Kuipers and Niederreiter, *Uniform Distribution of Sequences*  there are some results that might help you.

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting. If I understand correctly, the strategy is to use the Koksma–Hlawka inequality. This fails in my case because $f$ is an indicator function, which is not BV.

Comment: An indicator function  is BV with total variation $2$.

Comment: Oh, of course, sorry, how stupid of me. I'm a bit lost in this maze of theorems, but that does imply an upper bound on the hitting time, independent on $\theta_0$. The downside is that this bound depends on the diophantine approximation of $\alpha$. Even in what seems to be the most favorable case of $D_N = O(log N / N)$, I get lower bounds which are solutions of $\alpha n = log n$, and so grow (a bit) faster than $1/\alpha$. I was hoping for hitting times on the order of $1/\alpha$, but hey, that's life. Maybe other methods can do better though. Thanks!

Comment: There is a theorem of W. Schmidt (Thm. 2.3, Chap. 2 of Kuipers and Niederreiter) that says that $\frac{\log N}{N}$ is the best that you can hope for.

Comment: Yes, but this is to get strong bounds, ie bounds on $N(n)$ uniform in $\theta_0$. I'm still hoping for faster rates on hitting times averages. 

Comment: The following is only anecdotal: The lowest natural power of $2$ whose decimal representation begins with a '$9$' is $2^{53}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a theorem of Kesten, which roughly says, that if you take $(\theta, \theta_0)$ random, and the number of times you hit $(0, \alpha)$ in the first $N$ iterations, subtract the expected $N \times \alpha$, and normalize by $\rho \times ln(n)$, the result will converge to Cauchy distribution. This can be viewed as an analogue of CLT in this case.

Comment: That's amazing. I'm accepting that as an answer, thanks! The reason I'm interested in this is that I've  got some numbers from a simulation that I'm trying to explain. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try and fit this Cauchy distribution, and see where that takes me.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very nice question! A lot of results (and references) are given in [Zaq Coelho's "The loss of tightness of time distributions for homeomorphisms of the circle".](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~zc3/download/circlimlaw.ps.gz)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The question seems harder than I thought! The limit $\alpha \to 0$ is precisely the case I'm interested in. If I understand correctly the paper, it says that when $\varepsilon \to 0$, one can find subsets of nonzero measure whose hitting time arbitrarily exceeds the expected return time $1/\varepsilon_n$. That's unsettling, but fair enough. 

What about the case $\varepsilon$ fixed? I did not know about Kac's Lemma, is it invalid outside $J_\varepsilon$? Ie is $\int_{S^1} \tau(\omega) d\omega \neq 1/\varepsilon? If so, what's it equal to? This would be an answer to my question.